Barbarians attack a family and only little girl survived and taken care by another family
I remember only a few things, well it begins when a family (mother father brother and little girl with her doll) were travelling somewhere in a small boat when some barbarian people or something like that ( I thought maybe native Americans but not sure because maybe not) attacked them and killed the whole family and when someone ran after the little girl he looked at her and didn't kill her.
Later the girl was taken by a family that lives there and they at first didn't know what was her name because she stopped talking for a while ..then she lives with them and even get married to the oldest son (?) something like that!
Finally she gave birth to a child. 
Can't remember the name or any other details. It was an American movie and I don't know what year it was released but it's an old movie like 90s maybe.

This sounds like a scene in the Steven Spielberg miniseries called "Into the West" that aired in the summer of 2005 in the U.S.  Keri Russell portrays the woman who eventually falls in love with the son and has a child with him.

@steelersquirrel Are you sure about this? AFAIK she wasn't a little girl there and they weren't attacked on a boat.

@Walt No.  I'm not 100% sure.  I have seen the miniseries once.  I just remembered a scene similar with Keri Russell.  I wasn't confident enough to post it as an answer.

no I dont think so because I watched it around 2002 or so ..I was too young to remember any other detail ..the thing I'm not sure about is the attackers and from where they are .. @steelersquirrel
